# Change the Volume OSD position

Tags: macos, display, sound-volume

Is it possible to change the position of the on screen display (OSD) of the volume indicator that appears when you change the volume with the keyboard? Right now mine is very low, and I thought it was supposed to be centered vertically on the screen. I'm on Mavericks if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not changeable, I have seen no hacks that allow the changing of that graphic.